I'm making a language switcher to a website how can I disable it or change its location on mobile devices?
I am making a language switcher, but I need to change its location based on the screen size because on mobile it gets out of the screen. How would I be able to do that?
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() { 
  /* SETUP MULTI-LANGUAGE */
  var defaultLanguage = 'en';
  var lang = location.pathname.split("/")[1];
  var defaultClass = 'lang-'+defaultLanguage+'';
  var itemParent = "nav [class*='collection'],nav [class*='folder'],nav [class*='index'],nav [class*='group']";
  if (lang == "" || lang.length > 2 ){
    var lang = defaultLanguage;
  }

  /* ADD LANGUAGE CLASSES */
  $('a[href="/"]').addClass('lang-'+defaultLanguage+'').parents(itemParent).addClass('lang-'+defaultLanguage+'');
  $('nav a:link:not([href^="http://"]):not([href^="https://"])').each(function () {
    var langType = $(this).attr('href').split("/")[1];
    var multiLanguageClass = 'multilanguage lang-' + langType + '';
    if (undefined !== langType && langType.length <= 2) 
      $(this).addClass(multiLanguageClass).parents(itemParent).addClass(multiLanguageClass);
  });
  $('nav button').each(function () {
    var langTypeFolder = $(this).attr('data-controller-folder-toggle').split("/")[0];
    var multiLanguageClass = 'multilanguage lang-' + langTypeFolder + '';
    if (undefined !== langTypeFolder && langTypeFolder.length <= 2) 
      $(this).addClass(multiLanguageClass);
  });

  /* HOMEPAGE-LOGO LINKS TO PROPER LANGUAGE HOMEPAGE */
  if (lang == "pt") {
    $('a[href="/"]').attr("href", "/pt/inicio/");
  }

  /* ADD EXCLUSION NAV ITEMS */
  $('.exclude-me,.exclude-me a').addClass('exclude');
  $('.sqs-svg-icon--list a,.SocialLinks-link,.header-menu-controls-control').addClass('exclude');

  /* REMOVE OTHER LANGUAGES AND KEEP EXCLUDED ITEMS */
  $('.multilanguage:not(".lang-'+lang+',.exclude")').remove();
});
</script>
<script>
/*setup language switcher*/
$('body').prepend('<div class="language"><a href="/en/home" class="lang-en">English</a> | <a href="/pt/inicio/" class="lang-pt">Português</a></div>');
</script>

I'm new to making websites and I don't know how to change the location of my language switcher on mobile phones because it gets out of the screen oh, and if it helps I'm using squarespace to make the website and all the code is being injected on the footer. And I already tried this solution putting all the code inside a div element.
And maybe I am asking for too much but could anyone also help me make it so it adjusts to the size of the screen? Because it gets on top of other things when the screen is smaller.
<style>
  /* Hide content on mobile */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .desktop-only {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>


Your script isn't what's important here. This is a layout issue, and therefore we need to see your HTML markup.

Also, your title question and your post don't align very well. Your post says nothing about disabling anything--just about changing the layout. Please fix that for clarity.

It might be time to move away from Square Space, when you're starting to think about a multi-lingual web site. I know, that's not an easy step, but Square Space simply doesn't support multiple languages. Everything you do is a botch, complicated, or costs extra money.

Should this question have the CSS tag?

Hello everyone, thanks for the help, and sorry if the question is badly made or confusing, I am kinda new to this,i'll try to fix the post.

And to clarify why I am using squarespace in the first place is that my employer asked me specifically to use it.

As you are using language class so apply css on this.
If you want to go with .desktop-only, add this in your html after class .language too.


$('body').prepend('<div class="language desktop-only"><a href="/en/home" class="lang-en">English</a> | <a href="/pt/inicio/" class="lang-pt">Português</a></div>');
.language {
  display: block;
}

/* Hide language switcher on small screens (mobile or tablets) */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .language {
    display: none;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Thanks for the help, I will try doing that tomorrow as I don't have more time today, if it works I will mark this as resolved and thank you!
